# Why this error "Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+'" displayed?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics Api with Apps Script and trying to filter some pages using regular expressions.
But always this error displayed.

Invalid value '{filters=ga:pagePath=~(/burm)|(/4assort)|(/mkn)|(/apl)|(/grp)|(/pea)|(/arakawa)}'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+'

I tried some simple expression, for example,

```
var ReEx ='(\/abc)|(\/def)';

'filters':'ga:pagePath=~'+ ReEx
```

Is there something incorrect expressions in my code?

Therefore I tried to filter a single page. and it still same error returned.

```
function getCart(){
  return '/ShoppingCart.html';
  }

  var Cart = {
  'filters':'ga:pagePath=~'+getCart()
  }

  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(//
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      Cart
     ); 
    sheet.getRange(3, 7).setValues(results.getRows());
```

Comment: try testing with this its faster https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: Share your code snippet.

Comment: Have you prefixed "ga"?

Comment: Sorry, I've just noticed my mistake that I didn't specified dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by naming `pagepath` in small caps also make sure there are no spaces:

```
ga:pagepath==/prodcuts/motors
```

or

```
ga:pagepath=~/prodcuts/motors
```